# Set Background Image of a view with stretch to fit in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new with Xamarin. I'm actually trying to set the background image of a view and stretch it.

The image is a 2048x1536 pixels png.

```
nfloat vpHeight = View.Bounds.Height;
nfloat vpWidth = View.Bounds.Width;
Console.WriteLine(vpWidth);
Console.WriteLine(vpHeight);
```

The above code will return me 1024x768 (it's a landscape position).

```
var img = UIImage.FromFile("pages/p1.png");
UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(img);
imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

var prevPage = new UIView()
{
    Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight)
};
prevPage.Add(imgView);
```

this is the code where I set the background, but the result is just the half of the image in x and y just like the image bellow:

[image]

So, how to make the image to adjust to the width and height of the view ?

ty !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create an `UIImageView` as a background like so:

```
var img = UIImage.FromFile("pages/p1.png");
UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(img);
imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
```

then add this to whatever view you are using.

ContentMode can be used like so:
[image]

**Update**
I would add it to the prevPage like so:

```
var prevPage = new UIView()
{
    Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight)
};

var img = UIImage.FromFile("pages/p1.png");
UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0,0,vpWidth,vpHeight));
imgView.Image = img;
imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit; // or ScaleAspectFill

prevPage.Add(imgView);
```

Also its worth noting that using the View.Bounds to position the view is bit clunky. I would take a look into Autolayout as you will encounter problems on different devices and orientations. These are some good tutorials on Autolayout they might be native code but you are looking for the relationships of the views rather than the code.

[Raywenderlich tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXCzc.png)

[Other Tutorial](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/)

Any probs with autolayout just ask another question.

Comment: Slow down ! ty ! but how to set your code as background of the view ? I'm actually trying :    var prevPage = new UIView()
   {
    Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight),
    BackgroundColor = imgView
   }; -- but this is not working.

Comment: Ty, Ian, but it's still produce the very-very same result as the initial. I edited my code snippet as you can see in the beginning of this thread and I placed exactly your code there.

Comment: I have updated the code slightly, setting the imageview with a img will make the view that size so i have just set to the size of the view you are adding it too. That should fix it, I would still take a look into autolayout if you can.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you stay away from `FromPatternImage` unless you are really using a *pattern*.

For the lowest memory consumption and best UI performance, this is what I do:

1st) Resize your image using an image context to match the size of the view:

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(View.Frame.Size);
UIImage.FromBundle("bg.jpg").Draw(View.Bounds);
var bgImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

2nd) Display the resized image in a `UIImageView` and send it to the lowest Z-order:

```
var uiImageView = new UIImageView(View.Frame);
uiImageView.Image = bgImage;
View.AddSubview(uiImageView);
View.SendSubviewToBack(uiImageView);
```