# BackgroundImage tiling not filling on IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've set a BackgroundImage in XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.HomePage"
             BackgroundImage="HomePageBackGround.jpg">
```

This works, it sets the background image. The problem is, on IOS the image is tiled, and I want it to fill the whole screen. How can I do this? I've set appropriate sized copies (@2x and @3x for IOS and in the various drawable folders in Android) - it works as expected on Android but has the tiled behavior on IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with **RelativeLayout** :

Using RelativeLayout and constraint expressions, we can more or less achieve the same result as Windows XAML’s “Uniform”.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BackGroundImageDemo.StartPage" >
  <RelativeLayout>
    <Image Source="Jupiter.png" Opacity="0.3"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
    <Grid RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">

      <Label Text="Hello world from XAML" VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="30"/>
    </Grid>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is [the article](https://dzone.com/articles/using-full-size-none-stretched) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Was trying to go for the simple option rather than adding more complexity to an already complex layout, but I'll see how this goes.

Comment: Okey,the Grid with the actual UI in it.Just put the original layout into the Grid.In addition, it can also be implemented by the method of customrender.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557769/set-background-image-of-a-view-with-stretch-to-fit-in-xamarin) Here is the method of forms.